# QGIS - turning imported CAD drawings into usable point layer

Tags: qgis, autocad, dxf

I have the following problem. I got a DXF file containing locations of trees in an urban park. They are represented by symbols as seen below:

[image: CAD layer]

Stars (which are 10 single lines touching) are coniferous and 5 curved lines are deciduous. I want to convert them into points, which will be usable for a dendrologist. Problem is there are no attributes that identify a symbol as a single entity (attribute table has no specific column for numbering them). QGIS sees every line as a single feature, what can I do to make him see every symbol as a feature and then convert to points?

Comment: SO is not a place to ask for programs to be written and your question is liely to be closed. Consider contacting us privately as companies because some of us do commercial developing and we can look at your drawing and assist you.

Comment: I actually have a couple of ideas on how to proceed in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The process of transferring the CAD drawings in the `.DXF` file to QGIS is quite simple.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358339/importing-dxf-in-qgis-3-10

In the article below you can find it even without **georeferencing**.

http://www.mkrgeo-blog.com/good-solution-to-georeferencing-the-autocad-dwg-drawing-in-qgis-3x/

Next, your CAD drawing becomes a layer, which can be simply **turned into points** (from lines to points I guess).

https://wiki.tuflow.com/index.php?title=QGIS_Convert_Lines_to_Points

The last step is your **data attribute table**. It requires cleaning not-needed columns from your CAD drawing and creating new ones.

https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html

Depending on your situation, probably some things you have to input manually, but other ones can be calculated straight away by using the **field calculator option**.

I have no idea what do you want to calculate, so I am posting a kind of general answer.

Comment: thanks but I have no problems importing the DXF file. The problem is that I can interpret the geometries as individual trees but I have no idea how QGIS can do it too.

Comment: I think you should take a look at the data attribute table in QGIS and define the field values for the given type of tree. I guess other values will come out for the star shapes and others for ovals. That would simplify your issue a lot.

Comment: as I said attribute table doesn't contain any values that allow any sort of identification.